# Python Calling MySql stored proc that returns multiple results sets and formatting these as a series of tables

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, html-table

I have a mysql stored proc comprising multiple select statements. I want to output this to an email in a series of tables. I've already tested the email element so my focus in this request is just to print out the result tables to the command line.

This seems like it should be a relatively common common thing to do, but I can find no worked examples online. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I am trying code like this:

```
import mysql.connector
from tabulate import tabulate
 
# MySQL database configuration
mysql_config = {
    'host': 'your_mysql_host',
    'user': 'your_mysql_user',
    'password': 'your_mysql_password',
    'database': 'your_mysql_database',
}
 
# MySQL stored procedure name
stored_procedure_name = 'your_stored_procedure_name'
 
def execute_mysql_stored_procedure(mysql_config, stored_procedure_name):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
        cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
 
        # Execute the stored procedure
        cursor.callproc(stored_procedure_name)
 
        # Fetch all result sets
        results = []
        while True:
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if not result:
                break
            results.append(result)
 
        return results
 
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(f"Error: {err}")
 
    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
 
def format_result_sets(result_sets):
    for i, result in enumerate(result_sets):
        print(f"\nResult Set {i + 1}:\n")
        if result:
            headers = result[0].keys()
            rows = [list(row.values()) for row in result]
            table = tabulate(rows, headers, tablefmt="grid")
            print(table)
        else:
            print("No results found.")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Execute the stored procedure
    stored_procedure_result = execute_mysql_stored_procedure(mysql_config, stored_procedure_name)
 
    # Format the result sets
    format_result_sets(stored_procedure_result)
```

But get the following error:

```
Error: No result set to fetch from
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myprog.py", line 57, in <module>
    format_result_sets(stored_procedure_result)
  File "./myprog.py", line 42, in format_result_sets
    for i, result in enumerate(result_sets):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I have done some testing with other versions of the code and I can successfully get output from the query but it is the form of a group of MySQLCursorBufferedDict objects and again I'm not sure how to manipulate these into a series of tables, so that could be an alternative solution is it is easily done.

Updated with solution, including conversion to tables:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from contextlib import closing
import mysql.connector
from tabulate import tabulate

engine = create_engine( 'mysql+mysqlconnector://dbuser:password@dbhost/dbname', echo = False )
connection = engine.raw_connection()


try:
    with closing( connection.cursor() ) as cursor:
        cursor.callproc( 'MySP')

        data = []
        for sr in cursor.stored_results():
            #--
            columns = [ column[0] for column in sr.description ]
            ds = sr.fetchall()

            dataset = []
            dataset.append( columns )
            headers = columns
            rows = [list(row) for row in ds]
            table = tabulate(rows, headers, tablefmt="grid")
            print(table)
            #--
            sr.close()

        cursor.close()

 
except Exception as e:
    print( f'Exception. Type {type(e)}: {str(e)}' )
finally:
    if 'connection' in locals():
        connection.close()
```

Comment: You need to call `cursor.nextset()` to go to the next result set.

Comment: See also https://dev.to/behainguyen/python-executing-mysql-stored-procedures-which-return-multiple-result-sets-1cif

Comment: Thanks so much @Barmar for the link. I have updated the question to include the code I used to generate the tables.